# A Markov Chain problem concerning a flea moving around a triangle

Tags: probability, markov-chains

A Flea moves around the vertices of a triangle in the following manner: Whenever it is at vertex i it moves to its clockwise neighbor vertex with probability $p_i$ and to the counterclockwise neighbor with probability $q_i=1-p_i$, $i = 1,2,3.$ Let $p_1=p_2=\frac{1}{2}, p_3=\frac{2}{3}$
$(a)$ Find the proportion of time that the flea is at each of the vertices.
$(b)$ How often does the flea make a counterclockwise move that is then followed by five consecutive clockwise moves?

---

My solution:
For $(a)$:
Let the states $1,2,3$ be the three vertices of a triangle. We then have the following transition probability matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}           \\[0.3em]
       \frac{1}{2} & 0           & \frac{1}{2} \\[0.3em]
       \frac{2}{3}           & \frac{1}{3} & 0
     \end{bmatrix}
Then by solving the linear equations(omitted) for the limiting probabilities, I got $\pi_1=\frac{10}{27},\pi_2=\frac{8}{27},\pi_3=\frac{1}{3}.$

For $(b)$:
Here's the place I am not so sure of. And I did: 
Let $cc$ be the event that the flea moves counterclockwise and $c$ be the event that the flea moves clockwise.
Then I computed the long-term probabilities for moving clockwise and counterclockwise as follows:
\begin{align*}
P(cc)
&=P(cc|\text{at vertex 1})P(\text{at 1})+P(cc|\text{at vertex 2})P(\text{at 2})+P(cc|\text{at vertex 3})P(\text{at 3})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{10}{27}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{8}{27}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\\
&=\frac{12}{27}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P(c)
&=P(c|\text{at vertex 1})P(\text{at 1})+P(c|\text{at vertex 2})P(\text{at 2})+P(c|\text{at vertex 3})P(\text{at 3})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{10}{27}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{8}{27}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}\\
&=\frac{15}{27}
\end{align*}

And if we want the probability of a counterclockwise move followed by five consecutive clockwise moves, we simply multiply the probabilities: $\frac{12}{27}\left(\frac{15}{27}\right)^5$

Is this the correct approach? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have the probability of a counter-clockwise (**w**iddershins) turn :$$\mathbb P({\rm w})= \pi_1q_1+\pi_2 q_2+\pi_3q_3$$

And the probability of a **c**lockwise turn: $$\mathbb P({\rm c})=\pi_1p_1+\pi_2 p_2+\pi_3 p_3$$

As I read it, the event of a counter-clockwise (**w**iddershins) turn followed by five subsequent **c**lockwise turns would likewise have a probability of:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P({\rm wccccc}) & = \pi_1 q_1 p_3 p_1 p_2 p_3 p_1 + \pi_2 q_2 p_1 p_2 p_3 p_1 p_2 + \pi_3 q_3 p_2 p_3 p_1 p_2 p_3
\\[1ex]
 & = (\pi_1 q_1/p_2+\pi_2 q_2/p_3+\pi_3 q_3/p_1)(p_1 p_2 p_3)^2
\\
& = \left(\frac {10}{27}\frac{1}{2}\big/\frac{1}{2}+\frac{8}{27}\frac{1}{2}\big/\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\big/\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\right)^2
\\ & = \frac{11}{486}
\end{align}$$

---

[Addendum]

Let's consider the probability of making two subsequent turns: widdershins then clockwise.  By your method (1) and my method (2) that would be:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P_1(wc) & = (\pi_1 q_1+\pi_2 q_2+\pi_3 q_3)(\pi_1 p_1+\pi_2 p_2+\pi_3 p_3)
\\ & = \bigg(\frac {10}{27}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{8}{27}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{27}\frac{1}{3}\bigg)\bigg(\frac {10}{27}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{8}{27}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{27}\frac{2}{3}\bigg)
\\ & = \frac{20}{81}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P_2(wc) & = (\pi_1 q_1 p_3+\pi_2 q_2 p_1+\pi_3 q_3 p_2)
\\ & = \bigg(\frac {10}{27}\frac{1}{2}\frac 2 3+\frac{8}{27}\frac{1}{2}\frac 1 2+\frac{9}{27}\frac{1}{3}\frac 1 2\bigg)
\\ & = \frac{41}{162}
\end{align}$$

The difference is that your method considers **each subsequent step to begin from an unknown start** and concatenates them together.

My method observes that **each subsequent step depends on where the previous step ended** with *only* the original step being from a completely unknown start.

Comment: So what is the problem of my approach?

Comment: @user73645  Your method calculates the probability of **each** *step starting from an unknown point*.  My method calculates the probability of **all** *steps starting from one unknown point*.  The difference is that the start of *every subsequent step* will depend on *where the previous step did end*.